# CodeIgniter Pagination for two different database results

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, limit, offset

I have two query results, a list of Courses and a list of user profiles. These queries are not related to each other.

I want to display the courses and user profiles in the same view. How do i set the LIMIT and OFFSET for each of these queries so that pagination works fine?

And what will be the pagination $config value like?

**What i tried!**

I have a method called *tabel_list()* in my model which returns the records and the total number of records returned.

For Courses:

```
$rows = $this->main_model->tabel_list($this->limit , $this->uri->segment(3), $joins, $order_by, $table, $select_fields, $condit, $group_by);

$data['total_rows'] = $rows['rows']['total'];
$records = $rows['list'];
$data['products'] = $records;
```

For User profiles:

> If something is true, retrieve the user profiles as well for the view.

```
$data['tutors'] = $tutor_records['list'];
$individual_rows = $tutor_records['rows']['total'];
$final_num_rows = $rows['rows']['total'] + $individual_rows;
$data['total_rows'] = $final_num_rows;
```

The configs:

```
$config['total_rows'] = $data['total_rows'];
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "home/courses/";
$config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Two result sets in one view AND working with one pagination. Help?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: How can you have two different pagination sets on the same view?  Does not make any sense.  Click on page 2 for the first set of data, then after the page reloads with page 2 of set 1, what is the second set of data supposed to show?

Comment: @Sparky If you read the question, I have explained the need to include two sets of results on the same page. A list of courses and user profiles. These results come from two different queries. I have found a solution. You can have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Simo I was not able to accommodate two sets of query results in one view. There is a situation where a user might want to just view a list of courses or just the profiles. I set the query offset to 20 for each. If my config['per_page'] = 20, and the results need to be displayed from both query results, I was not able to accommodate both results into one view and one pagination. If user wanted just one type of result, it was working. Check my answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, this is the solution to my problem.

I wanted two sets of results to be in one view. 
I want 20 records to be displayed in one page. So,

```
$config['per_page'] = 20
```

If the user wants just the list of courses, only one query runs, else two query results are to be displayed. What should be the offset of the queries?

Well, a simple conditional check/flag can determine if the user wants two sets of results and if he/she does want two sets of results, divide the current page index by 2. So you will have 10 results of each result set on the page.

```
if(user wants two sets of results on the same page))
        { 
            $offset = $this->uri->segment(3) / 2;
        }
```

If the user wants just one set of results,

```
$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Now use the limit of 20 and this $offset in your database query.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

Place two paginations on your page, one for each table.

Fill the smaller table with empty rows and do a post calculation of the limit for your 
query.

But it sounds, that your problem is before outputing and the pagination.